# django group by queryset in form ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model having image and reference field (reference is a string value). I need to filter the images list by reference, and a reference can have multiple images.

Now I'm wishing a dropdown menu having reference field values. How can I do that.

Here is the model

```
class AllImg(models.Model):
    ref_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img_name = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/allimg/')
```

now in my view of showing the list of `AllImg` model i have to filter them by `ref_by` field. I'll set the value of the `ref_by` in session and show the list according to that value. And if nothing is set in that session key, all entries of `AllImg` model will be shown.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Can you provide related model to AllImg.

Comment: You can run ALLImg.objects.all().values('ref_by', 'img_name').annotate(..)

Comment: lets say i have 100 entries in all images. some of them have ref_by=**ref1**, some have ref_by=**ref2**, and some have ref_id=**ref3**. Now I want a dropdown menu to have ref1, ref2, ref3 in options value and as well as in text

Comment: @MdMasudurRahman did you check my answer below?

Comment: @ozgur yes. Your answer did what I wanted. But it gives an error  _Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices_

Comment: @MdMasudurRahman you are doing sth different than what you've asked in your question. Please tell us where you are stuck thoroughly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  ALLImg.objects.all().values('ref_by', 'img_name')
```